# Polars: Fill missing months per group

Tags: python, data-cleaning, python-polars

I want to fill in missing months in a data frame per group based on the minimum and maximum date in each group.

This approach works but uses `polars.apply`.

```
import polars as pl
import numpy as np
from datetime import date

DATA_SIZE = 10000000
raw_df = pl.DataFrame({
    "id": np.random.choice(range(0, 10000), DATA_SIZE),
    "date": pl.date_range(date(1940, 1, 1), date(2020, 1, 1), interval="1mo").sample(DATA_SIZE, with_replacement=True),
    "value": np.random.rand(DATA_SIZE)
})

clean_df = (raw_df
    .groupby("id")
    .agg(
        pl.struct([pl.col("date").min().alias("startDate"), pl.col("date").max().alias("endDate")])
        .apply(lambda row: pl.date_range(row["startDate"], row["endDate"], interval="1mo")).alias("date")
    )
    .explode("date")
    .join(raw_df, how="left", on=["id", "date"])
    .with_column(pl.col("value").fill_null(0))
)
```

Now that `date_range` accepts expressions there should be a more elegant and faster solution, but I can't get it to work: `ValueError: did not expect value <built-in function id> of type <class 'builtin_function_or_method'>`

```
(raw_df
    .groupby("id")
    .agg([
        pl.col("date").min().alias("startDate"), pl.col("date").max().alias("endDate")
    ])
    .select([
        id, pl.date_range(pl.col("startDate"), pl.col("endDate"), interval="1mo")
    ])
)
```

How can I use the `date_range` with expressions?

Comment: I think we would need to accept expression in the `date_range` to be able to do that.

Comment: Yes. I created two enhancement requests for this: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/5159 https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/5231
I was pointed to the upsample method which can serve as a workaround, but it is actually slower than the approach above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct but you have a little syntax error, you missed the quotation marks around "id". The error message is a little bit cryptic since `id` is also a function.

```
(raw_df
    .groupby("id")
    .agg([
        pl.col("date").min().alias("startDate"), pl.col("date").max().alias("endDate")
    ])
    .select([
        "id", pl.date_range(pl.col("startDate"), pl.col("endDate"), interval="1mo").alias("date")
    ])
    .explode("date")
    .join(raw_df, how="left", on=["id", "date"])
    .with_column(pl.col("value").fill_null(0))
)
```

Comment: Oh my, I was so fixated on the date_range part that I couldn't see the forest for the trees. I added the last explode/join/with_column part to the code to complete the answer. Not sure if you can approve it. Speed-up is about 20% on my machine.